# How to handle 1 or 2 NULL in a calculation

Tags: t-sql, case

```
SELECT trends.[PreviousSales]
       , trends.[CurrentSales]
       ,CASE WHEN trends.[CurrentSales] - trends.[PreviousSales] IS NULL 
             THEN 0 ELSE trends.[CurrentSales] - trends.[PreviousSales] 
             END AS [DeltaSales]
```

Basically DeltaSales = CurrentSales - PreviousSales.  If either value is a NULL then the calculation obviously fails.
How can I restructure the CASE statement to substitute 0 when either of the Sales fields contain a null so the calculation executes properly?  The current CASE merely puts a ZERO in when the calculation fails.  A nested CASE maybe?

Comment: Is it __*always*__ appropriate to treat `Null` as zero in this calculation?  Also, bear in mind that it's not a "failure" to return `Null` from a calculation.

Comment: Yes it is always appropriate because a negative value has an important meaning as well which is not returned if CurrentSales is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using COALESCE ?

```
SELECT trends.[PreviousSales]
       , trends.[CurrentSales]
       , COALESCE(trends.[CurrentSales], 0) - COALESCE(trends.[PreviousSales], 0)
```

Comment: That's how I'd do it (actually, in SQL Server I'd cheat and use `IsNull()`, but `Coalesce()` is better because it's ANSI-compliant, and therefore portable.